# Putting in a hundred amp sub panel from a two hundred app panel

Tags: electrical-panel

What size service cable do I need to run a 100 amp sub panel from a 200 amp panel.

Comment: You should choose your subpanel based on having plenty of breaker spaces for future expansion.  Your feeder just needs to be <= the subpanel rating.   It doesn't have to match exactly, it's like the speed rating on car tires, you're not required to drive 112 MPH!